# Using Qthread to run a function

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I want to run a function of a class as a thread continuously,till the object of the class is destroyed.

client.h

```
class client:public QWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
   //some declarations

   client();
   void setclientui();
   //some ui elements
   void receiveme();  //i want this function to be run as a thread 
                      //It has to be run continuously to receive 
                      //messages from socket and when a message is 
                      //received ,it must display it in the gui.

 public slots:
   int prework();
   void sendme();
};
```

Note:`receiveme()` uses `recv()` of tcp sockets which gets blocked until message is received.

client.cpp

```
 void receiveme(){
 while(1){
    if(recv(sockfd,receivebuf,1024,0)<0)
    {
        qDebug()<<errno;
        break;
    }
   receivebuf[20]='\0';
    qDebug()<<receivebuf;
   outputbox->append(a);
}}
```

mainwindow.h

```
  class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Dialog* newdialog;//join a new chat
QString ipp,portt;
QTabWidget *wdg;
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void receivesocketaddress();
void on_actionJoin_a_chat_triggered();
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    wdg=new QTabWidget;
   ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_actionJoin_a_chat_triggered()
{
    newdialog=new Dialog();
    newdialog->setWindowTitle("Join a chat");
    newdialog->setModal(true);
    qDebug()<< QObject::connect(newdialog->conne,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(receivesocketaddress()));
   newdialog->exec();
}
 void MainWindow::receivesocketaddress()
{
     client *aclient=new client;
     aclient->iptoconnect=newdialog->ip->text().toLocal8Bit().data();
     aclient->porti=newdialog->port->text().toLocal8Bit().data();
     if(aclient->prework()==0)//ie connected
     {
        newdialog->close();
        wdg->addTab(aclient,tr("new chat"));
        setCentralWidget(wdg);
        //here the ui is shown.Now the aclient->receiveme() should
        //running
     }
     else
     {
        newdialog->displayerror();
        layout->addWidget(error,3,0,2,2);
        qDebug()<<"cud not connect";
     }
```

}

If `aclient->prework()==0` then a gui is displayed but how can i run `aclient->receiveme()` at this time as a thread so that it is continuously running and reading messages from socket.If a message is received,it should be displayed in the gui.

Without thread the gui would freeze.I tried to use `QThread::movetothread()` but i receive the following error

```
QThread::cannot move object with parent
```

and to use subclass method, `client` class must inherit `QThread` but since it is already inheriting `QWidget`,the following error is thrown

```
call to QObject is ambiguous
```

How can i use QThread here?

Answer (score 2):

1. Widgets can run only within GUI thread, so you need to implement `client` as `QObject` subclass and communicate with UI via signal/slot connection. Qt wont allow you to do `outputbox->append(a)` in non UI thread (Supposing that `outputbox` is some `QWidget` here);
2. You probably don't even need to use threads here - Qt provides it's own socket classes with event (signal/slot) based API;
3. If you still need to use `recv()` in different thread, you need to subclass `QThread` (one approach) or `QObject` (another approach); In both cases you need to have signal like `messageReceived(QByteArray)` that will be connected to slot in your UI object that will handle message; So `receiveme()` slot might looks like:

   `void client::receiveme()
   {
           while(1){
               if(recv(sockfd,receivebuf,1024,0)<0)
               {
                   qDebug()<<errno;
                   break;
               }
               receivebuf[20]='\0';
               QByteArray msg(receivebuf);
               emit messageReceived(msg);
           }
   }`
4. This [article](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/) might help